# How is koan study going to change, if at all, from LLM?

Tags: modern-world, koans

How is koan study going to change, if at all, from LLM? I am aware that koan answer books do exist, though I wouldn't where to find them. Will someone train LLM on them, making both koan study and new recorded sayings readily available to all, similar to the democratisation of art that we are promised?

Comment: what is LLM?...

Comment: @DhammaDhatu [Large Language Model (LLM)](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Large_language_model) - the AI technology behind ChatGPT

Comment: I'm inclined to close this question as opinion-based.